# We want to have a customized subscription form, that includes a coupon code input

Tags: coupon, recurly

As I understand it - I cannot use Recurly.js v3 for this... the hosted pages are not very pretty - so we want to style our own, however it seems like the coupon code field is not supported - and its very necessary for our business model.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely supported. Just add an input and use the `data-recurly="coupon"` attribute:

```
<input type="text" data-recurly="coupon">
```

You can see it in the [pricing section of the R.JS docs](https://docs.recurly.com/js/#recurly.pricing).

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated this into my application in few weeks ago. You can add the following to your page for the coupon code field.

```
<input type="text" name="couponcode" placeholder="Coupon Code" data-recurly="coupon_code" >
```

You can get the value by input field name **name="couponcode"**. Following is the PHP code.

```
'coupon-code'   => sanitize_text_field($_POST['couponcode'])
```